# Adwords: How to make the example scripts run (Python)?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

Before starting development, I would like to get some simple samples running. e.g. download_criteria_report.py ([link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201506/reporting/download_criteria_report.py)).

Developer Token is from an account pending approval.
Test account is created through this [guide](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts). Taken from the test account are these values:

- client ID (from created oauth credentials)
- client Secret (from created oauth credentials)
- client customer ID

With this data I am able to run the "get_report_fields.py" script ([link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201506/reporting/get_report_fields.py)). However, the above mentioned script (download_criteria_report) returns a
`ReportDefinitionError.CUSTOMER_SERVING_TYPE_REPORT_MISMATCH` error, which means afaik that I'm using a MCC account.
But to my understanding I am not using an MCC account but the test account. And what the developer token is concerned, I require an MCC account otherwise I am not able to get a developer token (otherwise the "Adwords API Center" in "Account Setting" is missing).

What is my error?

PS. In the future, I would like to make requests on behalf of other Adwords-accounts.

EDIT: Another try with following data:

- developer token: from MCC account (to my knowledge this must be an MCC)
- client ID: created oauth credentials from MCC account (the developer token owner account)
- client Secret: created oauth credentials from MCC account (the developer token owner account)
- client customer ID: from test account
- refresh token: from test account

I think, this should be the right way to access the (test-) adwords account. However, this ends with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The test account described in the guide ([link](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts)) is also a MCC account. Once logged into the test MCC, one must

1. create a child account
2. sign into the child account (click the account)
3. obtain a oauth refresh token (using the [generate_refresh_token.py](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/authentication/generate_refresh_token.py) for example) for this test child account (=> TCA)
4. use client Id and secret (from main account), developer token, refreshToken (TCA), client-customer-id (TCA)

Comment: Obviously, I am completely ignorant about Adwords. But to me the documentation does not make it easy at all.